# BlackBerry - BrowserField - NAVIGATION_MODE_NODE - OS 6.0 - Radio buttons don't work

Tags: radio-button, blackberry, browserfield

[OS 6.0, BrowserField, `NAVIGATION_MODE_NODE`]
I have a strange problem here...

I must develop an application (6.0) which will use the BrowserField for rendering some HTML files. It will use `NAVIGATION_MODE_NODE`, the keypad will be used to navigate from a focusable element to another.

I've created a HTML test file here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1441583/TestPage.html with some input fields.

All of them are working fine, only the radio buttons don't work.

- If I don't add `"checked="checked""` into a radio button (from a group - all radio buttons are unchecked), the group is skipped (no radio button from the group receives the focus);
- If I check a radio button from a group, only this checked radio button will be focused, but still I cannot select another radio button from the group - the rest of the radio buttons from the group are skipped.

The checkboxes are working fine...

```
final BrowserFieldConfig browserConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
browserConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
browserConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ENABLE_COOKIES, Boolean.TRUE);
browserConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ALLOW_CS_XHR, Boolean.TRUE);
browserConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_NODE);
```

I'm using 9800 and 9700 emulators (I don't have a 6.0 device), but somebody tested on a real device, and this wrong behavior is present too.
I've tested with www.google.com -> Settings (there are some radio buttons in that page), and the same: I cannot select another radio button from a group...

What I want to implement is: using the BrowserField, I want to navigate between controls using the keys.

Do you have a hint for that?
It's quite urgent...

Thank you very much,
Tibi.

I've tried on a BB 9780, and the combo-box doesn't work!
So, in NAVIGATION_MODE_NODE mode, the radio buttons and combo boxes don't work?
On some 6.0 emulators the combo boxes are working.
Do you have any clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER, otherwise it doesn't work. It sees your combobox as single node and that is why it is not showing properly.